# SELECT ordered by something, but the id with the same order value too

Tags: php, sql

i'm not that good with php, but I did the code below and hope for some little help:

```
<?php
    $next = '';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE x_column < '$x_column_variable' AND Column = '$column_variable' ORDER BY x_column DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $next_id = $row['ID'];
    if ($next_id != '') {
    $next = '<a href="****.php?id='.$next_id.'"><img src="img/next.jpg"/></a>';
     } 
     }

?>
```

The code works but when i have multiple ids with the same x_column value, it gives me only the first one and jump to the next x_column value.

Ex: if i have

```
12   78   2   2   1
```

i get only

```
78   12   2   1
```

Comment: You are selecting one column (`id`) and have `limit 1` on your query.  How could you be getting more than one value back?

Comment: Answer: Lose the `LIMIT 1`. Some remarks though: dont put your variables in a string. Use `"...". $var ."..."`, try looking at PDO as well, mysql is deprecated.

Comment: The fact that your query shouldn't work aside, you have two IDs with identical values and *that is a problem*. Usually if you have rows with identical values you use an ID field to distinguish between them, and having to identical IDs is massive failure in your logic and/or design.

Comment: Hi, i have unique ids but same value on the x_column

Comment: Nobody figured how to change this ? I need the limit 1 there because i need only the next id, not all ids at once. I get the id and i send it through url variable. I think i have to do something with "<", but if i change it into "<=" this doesn't work anymore. As I said now is working but when 2 consecutive ids with the same x_column value, it only gives me the first, and the second is jumped because of the "<". Maybe i don't express myself correctly, i'm sorry for that.